# Android Intent to create Contact using StructuredName

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts

I'm working on an app that create contact using Intent. Why using Intent you will ask : Because It's to let user modify the contact as they want before registering.

My problem is while I'm using **StructuredName** or **StructuredPostal**, for other CommonDataKinds it's working well. Here's my code:

```
 ContentValues name = new ContentValues();
   name.put(ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
   name.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, "Firstname");
   name.put(ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
   name.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, "LASTNAME");
 data.add(name);
 ContentValues row1 = new ContentValues();
   row1.put(ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
   row1.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.COMPANY, "company");
   row1.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TITLE, "position");
 data.add(row1);
 ContentValues row3 = new ContentValues();
   row3.put(ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
   row3.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website.TYPE_HOME);
   row3.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website.URL, "website");
 data.add(row3);
```

Here is StructuredPostal

```
 ContentValues row5 = new ContentValues();
  row5.put(ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
  row5.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY, "city");
  row5.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET, "street");
  row5.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE, "postcode");
  row5.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY, "country");
 data.add(row5);

i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
i.putParcelableArrayListExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.DATA, data);
startActivity(i);
```

Due to this problem I momentarily did a patch :

```
i.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, "Firstname LASTNAME");
i.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.POSTAL, "street, code city, country");
```

Someone knows what's wrong?

Thanks for answers :)

Answer (score 1):

For the **StructuredPostal** add the type. And use a different mimetype. Do not add null values for the address fields like street etc.

```
ContentValues row5 = new ContentValues();
row5.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
row5.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY, "city");
row5.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET, "street");
row5.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE, "postcode");
row5.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY, "country");
row5.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_HOME);
data.add(row5);
```

**StructuredName** does not work for me either.

Answer (score 0):

For using StructuredName in the Intent.INSERT you should add both Insert.Name and data row for StructuredName

`i.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, "Firstname LASTNAME");
    ContentValues name = new ContentValues();
    name.put(ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
   name.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, "Firstname");
   name.put(ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
   name.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, "LASTNAME");
   data.add(name);`

Same goes for StructuredPostal. You need to add Insert.POSTAL and the StructuredPostal data row.

The Insert.Name is taken as the DISPLAY_NAME and the rest of the fields are used for StructuredName. The Insert.POSTAL is used as formatted address. This is why you need to provide both data.

To see how android processes your Intent, check method parseStructuredNameExtra in this [file](https://github.com/android-ia/platform_packages_apps_ContactsCommon/blob/master/src/com/android/contacts/common/model/RawContactModifier.java)