# Android ContactsContract How to fill Prefix, Suffix structuredname fields via new Intent?

Tags: android, android-contacts, prefix

Most developers complain about the difficult API when trying to create an android system contact.
I want to create one with an intent, that is the contact app opens and has filled the appropiate fields from the passed intent data.
I know that I can set the first and the lastname just like this:

```
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, "Firstname Lastname");
```

The builtin contactapp splits the string automatically and sets the first words to the GIVEN_NAME field and the last word corresponds to the FAMILY_NAME field.

But adding the prefix and suffix words into that string dont fill the PREFIX, SUFFIX fields.

This also will have no effect, just as depicted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33650104/4859057):

```
ArrayList<ContentValues> data = new ArrayList<ContentValues>();
ContentValues name = new ContentValues();
name.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
name.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.PREFIX, "Sir");
name.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, "John");
name.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, "Doe");
data.add(name);
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.DATA, data);
startActivity(intent);
```

So how do I transfer the prefixes and suffixes to the contacts app via an intent?

The thing is, there are no official example codes to work with the contactsContract API, its just so frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

The way you build `ArrayList<ContentValues> data` seems ok, but then according to the docs it should be added to an intent using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Insert.DATA, data);

startActivity(intent);
```

So the full code would be:

```
ContentValues name = new ContentValues();
name.put(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
name.put(StructuredName.PREFIX, "Sir");
name.put(StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, "John");
name.put(StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, "Doe");

ArrayList<ContentValues> data = new ArrayList<ContentValues>();
data.add(name);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Insert.DATA, data);

startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Why is this not marked as Answer?